# Python: How to create a list with pairs of keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

How do I create a list with two indexes: The key and the appendant value of a dictionary. The key and the value should be random chosen out of the dictionary. I've already tried it with (these are my Latin words):

```
d = {}
d['house'] = "domus, domus"
da1 = d.items()
da = random.sample(wa1,1)
print (da)
```

When I do it like that, I get a list with only one index: The key AND the value. But I need a list with two indexes for being able to do:

```
dav = da[0]
dal = da[1]

def solution():
    dal = da[1]
    lbl.configure(text=dal)

def continue():
    dav = da[0]
    lbl.configure(text=dav)

lbl = Label(window,text=dav)
lbl.pack()

btnl = Button(window,text="Show solution",command=solution)
btnl.pack()

btnw = Button(window,text="Continue",command=continue)
btnw.pack()
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: What do you mean with "appendant"?

Comment: Can you show an example of the list?

Comment: is something wrong with accessing the elements the normal way `da1[0][0]` and `da1[0][1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting back a list which contains a tuple, which itself has two elements. For example:

```
da == [('house', 'domus, domus')]
```

You can index into that by using two indices:

```
>>> da[0][0]
'house'
>>> da[0][1]
'domus, domus'
```

If you want to make `da` into a list with two elements, you can do:

```
da = [x for x in da[0]]
```

Alternatively, you can just issue

```
da = random.sample(d.items(),1)[0]
```

to get a tuple with two elements

```
('house', 'domus, domus')
```

which you can make into a list with `list(da)` if that's required.

Comment: @user3764728 no problem. note that user41047's answer contains a better way to get your `da` using `random.choice`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select a random element, rather than a random sample:

```
>>> import random
>>> d = {'house': 'domus, domus', '???': 'something else'}
```

`random.choice` returns a `(key,value)`-pair:

```
>>> random.choice(d.items())
>>> random.choice(list(d.items())) # python3
('house', 'domus, domus')
```

Which we can unpack using tuple unpacking syntax:

```
>>> word, solution = random.choice(d.items())
>>> word, solution = random.choice(list(d.items()) # python3
>>> word
'???'
>>> solution
'something else'
```

Also note that `continue` is a python keyword, and can not be used as function name.

Comment: When I do it like that, I get the mistake 'TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing' when I run the program. The definition for solution is now only 'lbl.configure(text=solution)' and the def. for continue1 (the new command name) is 'lbl.configure(text=word)'. EDIT: I solved it by doing it with 'word, solution = random.choice(list(w.items()))' instead of 'word, solution = random.choice(d.items())'. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3764728: you found the right solution-- you're using Python 3, but user41047 is only using Python 2.  In 2, `.items()` returns a `list`.